# iPhone continuously redirects to the login page

Tags: mobile

iPhone gets continuously redirected to the (default FBA) login page asking for username and password. No error messages.
Anonymous authentication works fine (ie I can browser pages with iPhone).
All the desktop browsers can authenticate fine.

I have configured sharepoint not to redirect mobile devices to mobile pages (setting web.config browserCaps isMobileDevice filter to false, see http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/sharepoint2010customization/thread/3cb96ded-dce6-4391-8651-f57384547e14). Otherwise this is an out-of-the-box SharePoint with fba and ssl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enable cookies for safari, this was solution I've found to work.

Settings > Safari > toggle cookie settings.